# Persisting sorting in vaadin-grid in Polymer 2 app

Tags: vaadin-grid

I am using a vaadin-grid in a Polymer 2.0 application with several columns that almost all have a vaadin-grid-sorter. Since I would like to give the user a chance to persist its sorting preferences my question is:

Can I set the column to sort by and the sort direction in code?

I had a short look at the grid source code but didn't find any (public) property for that.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a `direction` attribute for `vaadin-grid-sorter`, you can set the value to `asc` or `desc`. And set the `path` attribute for the property in the item used for sorting. For example:

```
<vaadin-grid-column>
    <template class="header">
        <vaadin-grid-sorter path="date" direction="desc">Date</vaadin-grid-sorter>
    </template>
    <template>[[item.date]]</template>
</vaadin-grid-column>
```

Comment: Thanks, yes, I have seen that but the problem is: how do I set the active grid sorter (almost all my columns have a sorter)? Or does a grid sorter that gets set its direction automatically become the active one?

Comment: @NicolasR You are right. When every column has its own sorter, the one which gets set by user automatically becomes the active sorter, all the other sorters will be persistent with it.

Comment: @YuKitAs I am facing some problem while sorting. By default it seems to sort text only when it starts with capital letters and the text with small letters are ignored or simply not sorted. How to write the customize sort here or modify the default sort so that the sort will be irrespective of case of letters.